# Phonegap.build camera not working. What am I missing here?

Tags: javascript, html, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

For a school project, I have to make an app in PhoneGap.Build but I'm really struggling to say the least. One of the things I need to implement is the camera. It doesn't have to save the picture or anything, just activate the camera.

I have followed the following tutorial https://royduineveld.nl/app-maken-met-phonegap-en-phonegap-build/ which is in Dutch and rather old but I have looked at different forums and found stuff like this https://community.adobe.com/t5/PhoneGap/cordova-plugin-camera-not-working-on-android-device/td-p/9723868#10341001. I have tried quite a lot of solutions now but nothing seems to work. I also tried to read the documentation on the plugin as well but it is hard to understand. I don't have basic knowledge of javascript and it is not part of my school's curriculum. Obviously I must be doing something wrong, but I don't know what. At the moment I just got a screen with a button and when I press it, nothing seems to happen. Please help me out. You'll find the code below:

(function()
{

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);


function onDeviceReady()
{

}


function cameraSuccess(imageData)
{

    $('#maak-foto').after('<img src="' + "data&colon;image/jpeg;base64," + imageData + '">');
}


function cameraError(message)
{

    alert('Er ging iets fout! ' + message);
}


$('#maak-foto').click(function()
{

    $('img').remove();


    navigator.camera.getPicture( cameraSuccess, cameraError, {
        quality: 50, // Foto kwaliteit
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL // Base64 gecodeerde afbeelding als resultaat
    });
});
```

})();

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Foto maken</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Foto!</h1>
        <button id="maak-foto">Maken</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

<
    http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.phonegap.hello-world"
        version   = "1.0.0">

```
<name>Camera App</name>

<description>
    Camera example app.
</description>

<author href="<a href="http://phonegap.com" target="_blank">http://phonegap.com</a>" email="support@phonegap.com">
    PhoneGap Team
</author>
<feature name="<a href="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/" target="_blank">http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/</a>>



<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm"/>
```

Comment: It gives the following error in chrome: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). And its talking about the phonegap.js here. I see that in my first try I forgot to put in the jquery. After I put it in, it won't install on my phone. I just get a message with: App not installed.